# Add the custom converter into XAML page as resource in VB.Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, converters

I've created a custom converter. I try to define it in a page. I can't find any good example for this in Vb.net. Because of namespaces difference between C#, the resources on the internet don't help me very much. For example on the Microsoft's page I don't see how it is defined on the XAML's header.

Here is what I did until now but get an error that the namespace is not founded.

**Converter:**

```
Public Class MyConverter
    Implements IMultiValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(values As Object(), targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
        Return values
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetTypes As Type(), parameter As Object,culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotSupportedException()
    End Function

End Class
```

**XAML page:**

```
<Page x:Class="KlantFische"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="MyConverter"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1108"
  Title="KlantFische">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

<!-- ERROR: The name "MyConverter" does not exist in the namespace "MyConverter". -->
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="SearchTermConverter" />  

    </Grid.Resources>
  </Grid>
</Page>

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Windows.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Partial Public Class KlantFische
    Inherits Page

Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Project layout:**

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to have declared your `MyConverter` class in any namespace, or did you just not show it? You need to use that namespace in your XML namespace definition in the XAML.

Comment: @Sheridan You are right, I haven't declared any namespace since I don't know how to implement it afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would move your `Converter` classes to a folder named `Converters` which would be in your main project folder, not the `AppCode` folder. Then you should be including a namespace in *all* of your classes like this (please forgive any VB.NET errors as I am a C# developer):

```
Namespace LipasoftKlantFische.Converters
    Public Class MyConverter
        Implements IMultiValueConverter

        Public Function Convert(values As Object(), targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
            Return values
        End Function

        Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetTypes As Type(), parameter As Object,culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
            Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

You should then be able to declare an XML namespace in your XAML pages like this:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:LipasoftKlantFische.Converters"
```

If that still doesn't work, you can try this one, but the first one should work:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:LipasoftKlantFische.Converters;assembly=LipasoftKlantFische"
```

Then you should be able to access your `Converter` like this:

```
<Converters:MyConverter x:Key="SearchTermConverter" />
```

Comment: the first one: `Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'LipasoftKlantFische.Converters' that could not be found.`

Comment: the second one: `Assembly 'LipasoftKlantFische' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference....`

Comment: It's very hard to suggest a solution without seeing all of your code, so all I can do now is to provide you with a link to the [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747086(v=vs.100).aspx) page at MSDN and hope that you can work it out.